# How to enable HTML5 local storage in javafx WebView

Tags: html, webview, javafx-2, local-storage

Is there a way to enable HTML5 local storage on a javafx 2.2 WebView? Whatever I do it seems that local storage is disabled/not available for the WebView supplied by javafx.
I even tested it using http://html5test.com which did indeed show that local storage isn't enabled.
could there be a js script that would enable it? 
Are there alternatives, given that I don't control the web pages that are being loaded into the WebView.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 local storage functionality is not implemented for JavaFX 2.2 WebView so there is no way to enable that feature with that JavaFX version.

HTML5 local storage is currently being implemented in WebView for Java 8, you can get a [preview version](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) to test out functionality as it is implemented.

The feature tracking issues related to this are:

- [WebView to support HTML-5 localStorage?](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27799)
- [Implement window.localStorage](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29584)

The JavaFX issue tracker requires a login to access, but anybody can sign up from the login page.