# Using the IE/Chrome HTML-Renderer in Java OR storing files with JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm currently trying to write a little application (Which doesn't require internet access - So it really only is a local application.), which should be kept really simple. I thought about simply using HTML(+CSS) and a bit of JavaScript, since that would largely be sufficient, but I also need to have access to the filesystem in order to store my data in some file, which isn't really possible in javascript (Yes, I crawled through quite a few posts about JavaScript & FileSystem, but I didn't like any of the solutions.)

So I thought about another way to do it: There is some nice Library called HtmlUnit which would allow me to basically simulate my JavaScript, while having the Java FileAccess - But then I won't be able to render it.

So, two questions:

1. Is it possible to somewhat declare a JavaScript File as "local" and thus gaining file-system permissions?
2. Many applications (Games etc) internally use Internet Explorer. Is it possible to use IEs (Or even Chromes/Firefoxes/Whatevers) renderer in Java? I don't like any of the rendering-libraries I found until now - Or just simply be able to execute js+html code as a local application?
3. I tried out .HTAs, and I absolutly hate them. It's just so... old. Nothing is possible there. It would be awesome to get a simple html/js application looking like in chrome, but being a local application.

Comment: Have you checked HTML5 storage features? maybe they can guide you in the right direction: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: Maybe checkout [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/tree/master)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q&A**

> 1. Is it possible to somewhat declare a JavaScript File as "local" and thus gaining file-system permissions?

No, it is only possible through [ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953135/893578) / plugins (e.g. [Java](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem) / [browser addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiddlyfox/?src=search)).

Others may suggest that JavaScript has data storage or file system.
But they are *not* local file system access, and you cannot read or write real files with them.

> 2. Many applications (Games etc) internally use Internet Explorer. Is it possible to use IEs (Or even Chromes/Firefoxes/Whatevers) renderer in Java? I don't like any of the rendering-libraries I found until now - Or just simply be able to execute js+html code as a local application?

[JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm)'s [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) [use WebKit as renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm).
Webkit is not a full browser, so it has less feature, e.g. [no localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429729/how-to-enable-html5-local-storage-in-javafx-webview), but you can replace most of them with Java code.

[SWT Browser](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html), as mentioned by another answer, also works as renderer but will [make it difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706222/create-cross-platform-java-swt-application/3204032#3204032) for you to package as single file, plus it depends on client to do install/update the browser.

> 3. I tried out .HTAs, and I absolutly hate them. It's just so... old. Nothing is possible there. It would be awesome to get a simple html/js application looking like in chrome, but being a local application.

It is possible to embed all resources into one HTML file using inline code and [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs).
Here is one of my projects that does it: [[source files]](https://github.com/Sheep-y/ufoafterlight-db/tree/development) [[single file deployable]](https://github.com/Sheep-y/ufoafterlight-db/blob/master/index.html).

Regardless, most browsers does not allow file write, as you no doubt already know, and Chrome is [especially hostile](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787#c10) against file access.

---

**Advise**

From my experience, the only feasible solutions are:

1. ActiveX HTML app
2. Native program, such as Java jar or .Net exe. (Or a jar packaged as exe)
3. Full blown web app with customised browser and tailor made launcher, e.g. in a usb stick / dvd / installer

I have done all of them, and I personally think Jar/Exe is the most balanced solution given your requirement.

Which is sad.  If metro app were easily deployable like exe I'd advise that instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to somewhat declare a JavaScript File as "local" and thus gaining file-system permissions?

Firefox extensions would have the necessary permissions to [access the file system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file).

> Is it possible to use IEs (Or even Chromes/Firefoxes/Whatevers) renderer in Java?

Yes, e.g. with the [SWT Browser Widget](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html) or [JavaFX WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this will be enough for you (using HTML5 storage features):

```
function saveFile(localstorage) {
  localstorage.root.getFile("info.txt", {create: true}, function(theFile) {
    theFile.createWriter(function(theContent) {
      var blob = new Blob(["Lorem Ipsum"], {type: "text/plain"});
      theContent.write(blob);
    });
  });
}
```

Browsers will ask users for permissions to store files in local system.

*[Credit where credit is due](http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html)*